# How to "correlate" columns in group by query?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, google-cloud-sql

Say input:

Table T1

```
row_num_unimportant   indicator
        1                 111
        2                 222
```

Table T2

```
row_num_unimportant   indicator   val_timestamp   val_of_interest2
        1                 112       timestamp2        value1
        2                 113       timestamp1        value3
        3                 114       timestamp3        value2
        4                 223       timestamp4        value5
        5                 224       timestamp5        value4
```

I'd like to see the JOIN results

```
indicator    min_timestamp    val_of_interest2
   111         timestamp1          value3
   222         timestamp4          value5
```

The difficulty is the have val_of_interest2 to correlate with the min_timestamp.

Say in a naive JOIN:

```
SELECT
  indicator,
  MIN(val_timestamp) AS min_timestamp,
  ???? AS val_of_interest2
FROM (
  SELECT
    t1.indicator,
    t2.val_timestamp,
    t2.val_of_interest2
  FROM
    T1 t1
    JOIN T2 t2
    ON (t2.indicator >= t1.indicator)
)
GROUP BY
  indicator
```

Basically, what do I put in the ??? part? (or do I need a different query all together?)

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am executing queries using my company's own SQL engine / Database, but the SQL syntax should be pretty standard, like BigQuery, Google Could SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not use `group by` for this.  One option is window functions:

```
SELECT indicator, val_timestamp, val_of_interest2
FROM (SELECT t1.indicator, t2.val_timestamp, t2.val_of_interest2,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.indicator ORDER BY t2.val_timestamp) as seqnum
      FROM T1 t1 JOIN
           T2 t2
           ON t2.indicator >= t1.indicator
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I will try it out